# fluent nhibernate hasone not working with referenced notfound ignore

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a strange problem with my mappings.

I have an class lets call it `Order` which can have a relation with itself (see it as a chain kind of thing). `Order` does not have to have a newer or older in the "chain".

The problem is related to a different referenced nullable property in this `Order` class. That property, lets call it `Person`, has the `NotFound.Ignore()` setting.

The person property has a reference to a non-existing object. When I load an Order, that reference throws a ObjectNotFoundException (`No row with the given identifier exists`). However, since I have `NotFound.ignore`, I expect that object to be null.

Here is my object:

```
public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
public virtual int OldOrderId { get; set; }
public virtual Order OldOrder { get; set; }
public virtual Order NewOrder { get; set; }
```

Here is my mapping:

```
Map(x => x.PersonId. "person_id").Default("0");
Reference(x => x.Person, "person_id")
            .Not.Update()
            .Not.Insert()
            .NotFound.Ignore()
            .Not.LazyLoad();

Map(x => x.OldOrderId, "oldorder_id").Default("0");
References(x => x.OldOrder , "oldorder_id")
             .Not.Update()
             .Not.Insert();

HasOne(x => x.NewOrder)
             .PropertyRef(x => x.OldOrder)
             .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

When I add the `.Constrained()` setting to the "HasOne" mapping, the `Person` is returned as null (which is right). But in that case can't create an order without a `NewOrder`.

Comment: It seems that this problem only appears when im using ´Session.Get<Order>(id);´. When i use "criteria" or "QueryOver" to list orders the ´Person´ property is null instead of non-existing object.

Answer (score 0):

the cause is that you mapped the foreignkeycolumn twice and set the default to `0` which is a legal id for NHibernate and not references nothing.

you have to plug in NHibernate to change that because if it is lazy loaded it will create a proxy which doesnt have a notfound.ignore

[0 in foreignkey to null reference](https://bitbucket.org/jfromaniello/hotgazpachoeg/changeset/87ac41c473ae)